# How to delete unused vertex groups?

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode, vertex-groups

I downloaded a model and found that there were way more vertex groups than bones in the armature. Is there a way to delete all vertex groups that are not assigned to a bone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may first wish to make sure these vertex groups aren't being used for something else such as particles, shape keys, modifiers, etc. Vertex groups are used for a lot of different things besides just bone weights. But assuming you still want to remove these groups, it can be done like this:

1. **Make sure all the bones of the armature are visible**. With the armature selected, go to the `Object Data Properties` tab of the properties panel, and make sure all the Layers with bones in them are visible (the ones with a dot have bones). <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click to select multiple layers.
   [image: Selecting Bone Layers]
2. **Enter weight paint mode**. From object mode, first select the armature, then select the mesh by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + clicking on it. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select `Weight Paint`
3. **Select all the bones** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
4. **Lock the selected groups** from the menu at the top of the viewport. `Weights` > `Locks` > `Lock Only Selected`
   [image: Locking selected bone weights]
   Or if you want to preserve some other vertex groups as well, use `Lock Selected` instead, and make sure all the groups you want to keep are locked.
5. **Delete the unselected groups**. In the mesh's `Object Data Properties`, press the drop-down arrow on the right of the `Vertex Groups` section. Then select `Delete All Unlocked Groups`.
   [image: Deleting unlocked Vertex Groups]